# Is Gradient Boosted Tree boosting on the residuals or on the complete training set?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, gradient-descent

Please note, this question is a [duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347265/is-gradient-boosted-tree-boosting-on-the-residuals-or-on-the-complete-training-s) on stats.stackexchange.com.

I'm just not getting an answer there. So I'll delete the unanswered and keep the answered as soon as I get the first answer.

It is not fully clear to me if Gradient Boosted Trees are boosting on the residuals of each stage or on the complete training set?

From the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting#Gradient_tree_boosting) it seems to me that the Overal "Algorithm" as explained for Gradient Boosting is boosting on the residuals but when the article explains "Gradient tree boosting" - residuals are never mentioned - emphasis is given to gamma-i which weights each individual weak learner added to the model.

So what is true now?

1. Is Gradient Boosted Tree boosting on the residuals or on the complete training set?
2. Gradient Boosted Tree weighting individual training examples as for example explained in AdaBoost?

Comment: Gradient Boosted Tree is on the residuals as mentioned in _Hands‑On Machine Learning with Scikit‑Learn and TensorFlow: Aurélien Géron, Page: 267_, I am not sure if I understand your second question.

Comment: Since you've stated that training is only on the residuals I assume the 2nd question is redundant - since ALL residuals are used for the next stage and they are all weighted equally (or not weighted at all) or in other words weighted by their error, correct?

Comment: Updated comment: Since you've stated that training is happening only on the residuals (and not on the training set X) starting from the 2nd weak learner I assume the 2nd question is redundant - since ALL residuals are used for the next stage and they are all weighted equally (or not weighted at all) or in other words their error is somehow their weight, correct?